# Debugging js error in specific browser version

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli

I'm debugging a Vue-cli 3 app, that uses Webpack 4 to build the bundle.

My bundle errors out on some older browser versions with the error on the very first line:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (**

Specifically, on the very first `(` in `(window["webpackJsonp"]=window["webpackJsonp"]||[])...`, and I can't find a proper name for this construct, and it also seems correct.

With some experimentation (a la git bisect) I have found that the above error occurs in Chrome 59, but is no longer present in Chrome 60. Firefox 54 still has the error, but 55 works.

How can I tweak babel/webpack to make these older versions work? I care, because Google Search Console seems to be using one of the older versions for indexing, and fails to render.

The page in question is available at:
http://phaidra.styts.com/#/detail/o:995887

And the source at:
https://github.com/styts/phaidra-ui

Comment: Can you post your webpack production build config?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the webpack config, since it's a Vue-cli 3 app, but here is the output of `vue inspect --mode production`: https://pastebin.com/F5jwsRxh